Examples of *uncountable* null and meagre sets that are not rare
I'm trying to teach myself real analysis, and I'm trying to figure out the various notions of "small" sets. My current understanding lead me to the following Euler diagram:

For the other regions in the diagram, there have been plenty of answers to be found on math SE; however I have not managed to find/come up with examples for the red-colord scenarios, namely:

A set that is meagre and null but not countable or rare (editted)
A set that is meagre but not null or rare


Once you get this chart taken care of, you might next consider stronger versions in which each "not small" notion (e.g. not finite, not countable, not measure zero, etc.) is replaced by "not small in each open interval", which might be called "densely not small". Note that it's automatically the case that "small" implies "small in each open interval", so it is not necessary to also consider "densely small" notions.

Old answer: A possible example for a set that is meagre and null, but not rare is $\mathbb Q$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ with the standard norm:
As is known, the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb Q$ is zero, so it is null, the closure of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$, so $\mathbb Q$ is certainly not nowhere dense (its closure has nonempty interior) and we can write $\mathbb Q$ as a countable union of rare (i.e. nowhere dense sets) as follows:
$$\mathbb Q = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\{\frac mn: m \in \mathbb Z \right \}.$$
The equality of $\mathbb Q$ to the right hand side should be clear and the fact that all the sets on the right are rare can be seen as follows: The closure of the set $\{\frac mn: m \in \mathbb Z\}$ is the set itself because all points are a positive distance of at minimum $\frac 1n$ apart. This implies that any converging sequence becomes constant eventually and hence all limit points are already in the set. The closure of $\{\frac mn: m \in \mathbb Z\}$ is hence the set itself which does not contain any interior points (all points are isolated in $\mathbb R$ and lie in a discrete lattice) and is therefore rare/nowhere dense.
New answer for part A: Take the standard $\frac 13$-Cantor set. It is nowhere dense and has zero Lebesgue measure. Its union with $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ still has zero Lebesgue measure (i.e. it's a null set), but due to density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ it is not rare (i.e. not nowhere dense). It is meagre however, since the Cantor set is nowhere dense and $\mathbb Q$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets (singletons in $\R$ are nowhere dense).
For the second part you could use a fat Cantor set like the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) in the interval $[0,1]$. It is a nowhere dense/rare set with positive Lebesgue $\frac 12$. If you then take the union of this set with $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ you are still meagre by the same argument as before for $\mathbb Q$; the Lebesgue measure hasn't changed, so you aren't null and you are also not rare anymore by density of $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ in $[0,1]$.

I think I should modify my question to clarify that by Scenario A I mean a uncountable one. Sorry I didn't state that clearly.

Oh yeah, sorry I missed that in your diagram. I would have to think about that for a while...Update: it should work if you take the standard $\frac 13$-Cantor set. It is nowhere dense, uncountable and has Lebesgue measure zero. Take the union with $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ and you have a meagre, null set which is not rare.

I think this is valid, and it also illustrates how to get a set for scenario B (simply replace the standard Cantor set with a fat one).
Would you kindly put these into the main body so I may accept it?
